# Android: Firebase ViewModel Architecture

Tags: android, firebase, android-architecture-components

I have viewModel class, firebase class, and a fragment.

In the fragment I'm observing microbes list from viewModel:

```
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(ViewModelMicrobes::class.java)
    viewModel.microbes.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { microbes ->
        var microbesList = mutableListOf<Microbe>()
        for(microbeMap in microbes){
            val microbe = Microbe(microbeMap["name"] as String)
            microbesList.add(microbe)
        }
        adapter.microbes = microbesList
    })

    viewModel.fetchMicrobes(this)
```

In the viewModel class I'm fetching microbes from the firebase class:

```
    fun fetchMicrobes(owner: ViewModelStoreOwner){
    val firebase = FirebaseMicrobes()
    firebase.fetchMicrobes(owner)
}

fun setMicrobes(microbeMaps: List<Map<String, Any>>){
    _microbes.value = microbeMaps
}
```

In the firebase class I'm fetching microbes and calling setMicrobes from the viewModel:

```
    fun fetchMicrobes(owner: ViewModelStoreOwner){
    val database = Firebase.database
    val microbesRef = database.getReference("microbes")
    microbesRef.addValueEventListener(object: ValueEventListener{
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            val children = snapshot.children
            val viewModel = ViewModelProvider(owner).get(ViewModelMicrobes::class.java)
            var microbes = mutableListOf<HashMap<String, Any>>()
             for(child in children){
                 microbes.add(child.value as HashMap<String, Any>)
             }
            viewModel.setMicrobes(microbes)
        }

        override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {

        }
    })
}
```

Is that a correct way to do it? I need to create a viewModel instance in the firebase class, so I'm passing "this" in the fragment when calling the viewModel's method, so then the viewModel's method can pass the owner to firebase class, so the firebase class can create viewModel instance.

Comment: *"I need to create a viewModel instance in the firebase class"* - you shouldn't need to do this at all.  If your "firebase class" is intended to serve as a repository in MVVM, it shouldn't be working with ViewModel objects, or receive any Android platform objects (like owner).  Your repository should instead expose something like a LiveData or Observable.

Comment: Thank you, I see what you're saying. would it be a good practice to put firebase network calls inside the viewModel? instead of creating two classes.

Comment: No.  Iteraction with data sources should only be done in a repository.  A viewmodel asks the repository the get data, then transforms it into whatever views require.  You should take a look at this documentation if you haven't already.  https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide#recommended-app-arch

Comment: Thank you that clarified the purpose of Firebase repo class. I wish I could accept your answer, but there is already one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing owner would not be a good option, instead you should define a livedata in ypur firebase class, while fetching data from viewmodel' fetchMicrobe() start observing Livedata passed from Firebase class, when response is received, post data to livedata, and as you are already observing this livedata in viewmodel class, set here your list. Thus without passing your owner you will be able to fetch data, Your code will be decoupled, will follow best practices and will be helpful in testing your code.

Comment: Thank you, wouldn't it be simpler to just put the firebase fetch method inside the viewModel? I don't think I need firebase class.

Comment: If you want to follow proper MVVM then you should have Firebase class, it is working as repository, and A completely separate component whose only responsibility is just to bring the data, Again it would be helpful for you while testing, passing mock data during testing.